# пустой тег Xmlpullparser

Tags: java, android, xml

Как спарсить пустой тег с помощью Xmlpullparser ?

```
<string/>
<string/>
<string>Work</string>
```

Вот пример кода

```
if (xpp.getName.equals("string") && xpp.getText().isEmpty() == false) //так не получается
 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NULL" ;
```

Нужно чтобы когда парсер наткнулся на самозакрывающийся тег в лог выводилось слово NULL

Comment: так ничего и не будет. `isEmpty` возвращает `true`, если объект пустой, а тут проверка, что объект не пустой.

Comment: @Александр даже при обратном не получается, есть какие то идеи?

Comment: попробуй просто `xpp.getText().isEmpty()`

Comment: @Александр все равно, не реагирует

Comment: если честно, меня смущает, что тег сразу закрывается, попробуй разделить, вот так: `<string></string>`

Comment: @Александр дело в том что его разделять смысла нету, так как xml скачивается с сервера